# Create/Update values based on parent products

Tags: mysql

I have two mysql tables

First table "products" has the fields product_id, seller_id and the product_parent_id which defines the parent product_Id of the product.

```
product_id    seller_id    product_parent_id
    1             1                 0
    2             1                 0
    3             1                 0
    4             7                 2
    5             7                 3
    6             8                 3
```

The second table "customfields" has the following fields: product_id and commission. In this table I only define products with a commission which have a seller_id = 1 and a product_parent_id of 0 in the first table.

```
product_id    commission
    1             A
    2             A
    3             B
```

I would like to write a mysql query to insert and if already available update the fields product_id and commission in the customfields table based on the parent product for child products.

Meaning I would like to add or update in the customfields table the products which have a seller_id > 1 and a defined product_parent_id and update the fields with the commission of the parent product.

The result would be:

```
product_id    commission
    1             A
    2             A
    3             B
    4             A
    5             B
    6             B
```

Unfortunately I am completely lost where to start. Could please someone be so kind and at least assist which a logical approach.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know in advance the amount of levels between children and parents? (parents, grandparents, grand-grandparents, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Simply join the `products` and `customfields` tables using `product_parent_id` as the joining relationship. Then use this as the source data in an `INSERT` statement.

Use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to update rows if they already exist.

```
INSERT INTO customfields (product_id, commission)
SELECT p.product_id, c.commission
FROM products AS p
JOIN customfields AS c ON c.product_id = p.product_parent_id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE commision = VALUES(commission)
```